# Anybody know how to return a file back to gwt client?

Tags: gwt, restlet

I am using Restlet FileRepresentation to get a file on the server side of gwt, and on the client side of gwt, I want to download this file.

I want the browser to show a download link, and download the file

I am also using Restlet Authentication, if I directly use Anchor, and set Href property to the target resource, each first time, I need to provide credentials even the user has already been validated.

So I am wandering if there is another way to do this?

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want the browser to show a download dialog or do you want to access the content of the file in your gwt programm?

Comment: I want the browser to show a download link (use Anchor?), and download the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the client side you just use an anchor `<a href="path/to/your/rest/service"></a>`. You can use [Anchor](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) widget.

On the server side, if you use any of the browser-supported MIME types (html, txt, pdf, swf, xml, json, etc..) and you do not want the browser to open this file, but rather show the download dialog, then you must set the HTTP `Content-disposition:` header. For example:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.txt
```

Apparently with Restlet [FileRepresentation](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/representation/FileRepresentation.html) you must call the `fileRepresentation.getDisposition().setType(Disposition.TYPE_ATTACHMENT)`.